# Verlet physics constraints

Tags: python, c#, physics-engine

I'm trying to create a simple physics solver from scratch using pygame. I was following a tutorial here:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lS_qeBy3aQI](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I got to the part where he creates the constraints (3:30 ish) but when I tested my code, the object would bounce repeatedly when it hit the bottom of the constraining section.

here is the code I'm using (note that I converted from the C# or C++ code used in the video into python, so that could be causing issues):

```
import os
os.environ["PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT"] = 'hide'
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from pygame import Vector2 as Vec2
import sys
pygame.init()

wnSize = (700, 700)
fps = 10

gravity = Vec2(0, 100/fps)
objs = [[i/2 for i in wnSize]]
objradius = 50

areaCenter = Vec2(wnSize[0]/2, wnSize[1]/2)
areaRadius = 350

class VarletObject:
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.poscurr = Vec2(pos)
        self.posold = Vec2(pos)
        self.acc = Vec2(0, 0)
    def updatePos(self, dt):
        vel = self.poscurr - self.posold
        self.posold = self.poscurr.copy()
        self.poscurr = self.poscurr + vel + self.acc * dt * dt
        self.acc = Vec2(0, 0)
    def accelerate(self, acceleration):
        self.acc += Vec2(acceleration)

class Solver:
    def __init__(self, gravity, objPoses):
        self.gravity = Vec2(gravity)
        self.objs = [VarletObject(i) for i in objPoses]

    def update(self, dt):
        self.applyGravity()
        self.applyConstraint()
        self.updatePositions(dt)

    def updatePositions(self, dt):
        for obj in self.objs:
            obj.updatePos(dt)

    def applyGravity(self):
        for obj in self.objs:
            obj.accelerate(self.gravity)

    def applyConstraint(self):
        for obj in self.objs:
            to_obj = obj.poscurr - areaCenter
            dist = to_obj.length()
            if dist > areaRadius - objradius:
                print(1)
                n = to_obj/dist
                obj.poscurr = areaCenter + n * (dist - objradius)

    def draw(self, wn):
        pygame.draw.circle(wn, (0, 0, 0), areaCenter, areaRadius)
        for obj in self.objs:
            pygame.draw.circle(wn, (255, 255, 255), obj.poscurr, objradius)
            pygame.draw.line(wn, (255, 0, 0), areaCenter, obj.poscurr)


wn = pygame.display.set_mode(wnSize)

solver = Solver(gravity, objs)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while True:
    wn.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    solver.update(1)
    solver.draw(wn)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

I've tried changing the gravity and size of the objects, and tried fiddling with the constraint detection and adding:

```
obj.posold = obj.poscurr.copy()
```

right after line 57 but that just caused the object to make smaller bounces not removing the underlying problem.

edit:
the important bits of code is the constraint detection function, in the video its:

```
void applyConstraint() {
    const vec2 position{800.0f, 450.00;
    const float radius = 400. Of;
    core::foreach<VerletObject>([&](VerletObject& Obj) {
        const Vec2 to_obj = obj.position_current - position;
        const float dist = MathVec2::length(to_obj);
        // 50 is the default radius
        if (dist > radius - 50.0f) {
            const Vec2 n = to_obj / dist;
            obj.position_current = position + n * (dist - 50.0f);
        }
    });
}
```

and from my code:

```py
for obj in self.objs:
    to_obj = obj.poscurr - areaCenter
    dist = to_obj.length()
    if dist > areaRadius - objradius:
       print(1)
       n = to_obj/dist
       obj.poscurr = areaCenter + n * (dist - objradius)
```

Comment: I suggest posting a [mre] that's just the suspect C++ and Python code and zero extra fluff. Should really cut down on the time and effort required to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you indicate how you made sure that `MathVec2::length(to_obj);` and `to_obj.length()` are equivalent functions?

Comment: I did not make sure, but I used the Wikipedia pages and the videos description of what was being done to figure out was he was trying to do at that point

Comment: Well if you gather the relevant documentation for those functions, that is the first step in the basic troubleshooting of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the (dist - 50.0f) or (dist - objradius), that was just moving it's radius closer to the center of the area. What it should be is (areaRadius - objradius).